# Given some integers, return the k most frequent elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, complexity, heap

Given a non-empty array of integers, return the k most frequent elements.

For example, given `[1,1,1,2,2,3]` and `k = 2`, return `[1,2]`.

Following is my submission to this problem on Leetcode and it is accepted. Can you please provide feedback on any issue that you see in this code? I am looking for improvements in the quality of the code from both software engineering perspective as well as from algorithmic complexity or space and run-time performance perspective.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Node
{
public:

    int value{};
    unsigned frequency{};

    Node()
    {

    }

    Node (int value, unsigned frequency)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->frequency = frequency;
    }

    bool operator< (const Node& other)
    {
        return this->frequency < other.frequency;
    }
};

class Solution {
public:

    vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) 
    {            
        map<int, unsigned> frequency;

        for (auto n : nums )
        {
            if ( frequency.find(n) != frequency.end())
                frequency[n]++;
            else
                frequency[n] = 0;
        }

        vector<Node> heap;

        for ( auto f : frequency )
            heap.push_back(Node(f.first, f.second));

        make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());

        vector<int> result;

        unsigned i = 0;
        while ( i < k )
        {  
            result.push_back(heap.front().value);
            pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end()-i);
            i++;
        }


        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just the general C++ coding style treatment.

1. Do not use `using namespace std;`. It can introduce subtle bugs, makes the code harder to read and writing out the `std::` prefix generally is not going to be to time intensive.
2. Keep your spacing consistent. Compare the following two lines

   ```
   bool operator< (const Node& other)
   vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k)
   ```

   Why is one method name followed by a space while the other is not? Consistency is important! If you are not sure which spacing variant to choose, you should read a [C++ style guide](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md). The same applies to control structures, such as

   ```
   for (auto n : nums )
   if ( frequency.find(n) != frequency.end())
   for ( auto f : frequency )
   ```
3. Use a member initializer list in your constructor. Although it does not matter in a lot of cases, it is a more concise way of expressing member initialization and leaves the constructor's body open for more complex setup tasks. The `Node` constructor would then look something like this:

   ```
   Node(int value, unsigned frequency) : value(value), frequency(frequency) { }
   ```

   Also, since you default constructor does not actually do anything, you should remove it and the initializers for `value` and `frequency` and add default values to the constructor parameters instead, so that `Node`'s constructor becomes something like

   ```
   Node(int value = 0, unsigned frequency = 0) : value(value), frequency(frequency) { }
   ```

   Keep in mind, however, that this constructor allows implicit conversions from integer types, which you typically want to avoid. This is easily prevented by making the constructor `explicit`.
4. Most people prefer to not write `this->` explicitly when not needed.
5. `const`-correctness is important. You should take the parameter `nums` in `topKFrequent` by `const`-reference since you do not actually modify it.
6. Always use curly brackets with `if`,`else`,`for`,`while` etc. This prevents a lot of errors from statements not being included in conditionally dependent blocks when they should be. In fact, this kind of error is so common that [gcc even introduced a diagnostic for misleading indentation in version 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html).

Comment: **2.** The Google C++ style guide is notoriously bad and outdated. At least link something a bit better like [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md). **3.** Congratulations on recommending to allow implicit conversion from `int`.

Comment: @Deduplicator I've edited the answer. I'm still curious as to what your point 1 was, though.

Answer (score 6):

#### Algorithm

Let's look at the time complexity of the different parts of the implementation:

- Build a `std::map` of frequencies: \$O(n \log n)\$. This could be improved to \$O(n)\$ by using a hash map instead.
- Build a max-heap of the `m` unique elements: \$O(m \log m)\$
- Pop the top `k` items from the heap: \$O(k \log m)\$

If `k` is very small compared to `m`,
then building a heap from the entire collection is overkill.
It would be better to build a min-heap of `k` elements.
That way, only `k` elements will be kept in heap order,
instead of the larger `m`.
The content of the heap will be the most frequent `k` elements.

If `k` is close to `m`,
then popping `k` elements is overkill.
It would be better to build a max-heap of `m - k` elements.
The elements excluded from the heap will be the most frequent `k` elements.

#### Variable scope

It's good to limit variables to the smallest possible scope.
For example here, the variable `i` is visible outside the loop,
but it's only used inside:

```
unsigned i = 0;
while ( i < k )
{  
    result.push_back(heap.front().value);
    pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end()-i);
    i++;
}
```

It would be better to rewrite this as a `for` loop,
that will make `i` visible only inside.

#### Program organization

Building the map of frequencies and then finding the `k` most frequent items are two independent steps.
It would be good to put these steps in separate private functions.

#### Pair of values

Instead your custom `Node`,
it would be better to use `std::pair`.

#### C++

I admit my C++ is pretty rusty,
I was not able to get this code to compile using `g++` or `g++ -std=c++11` or `g++ -std=c++14`.
I would like to think that it's possible to adjust this code so that it becomes trivial to compile.

Mainly I wanted to check if this part can be simplified:

> ```
> int value{};
> unsigned frequency{};
>
> Node()
> {
>
> }
> ```

To this:

```
int value;
unsigned frequency;
```

Because an empty constructor and the `{}` after field declaration seem pointless,
and I would like to code to be as simple as possible,
with as little noise as possible.

Comment: I was under the impression that collection classes often need empty constructors for them to work which was the sole reason for having it. I didn't verify it though.

Comment: @Stackcrashed every bit of code increases the complexity and mental burden of a program. Therefore it's important that every bit of code has a good reason to be there. If you don't why something is there, try to find out, and remove if unnecessary, keeping the code the minimal necessary.

Comment: Just verified; it's indeed not needed. So got rid of it. On a separate point, I needed to overload < operator. How would that work if I used a std::pair instead of custom class? Just pass a comparer function? Would that be overall a better approach?

Comment: @Stackcrashed yes, using an existing class and passing a comparer function would be better

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach would fully leverage the many standard algorithms and containers in the standard library.  Here's one such mechanism:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // test vector to demonstrate solution
    const std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,5};
    std::unordered_map<int, int> count;
    for (int i : input) {
        ++count[i];
    }
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;
    pairs.reserve(count.size());
    std::copy(count.begin(), count.end(), std::back_inserter(pairs));
    int k = 3;
    std::partial_sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.begin()+k, pairs.end(),
          [](const std::pair<int, int> &a, const std::pair<int, int> &b) {
                 return a.second > b.second;
           }
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        std::cout << pairs[i].first << ", " << pairs[i].second << '\n';
    }
}
```

### Output

The output to this sample program is the top `k` data items with their associated count:

```
1, 6
2, 5
3, 3
```

### Key points:

#### Use unordered containers for efficiency

One can use either a `std::map` as you have done, or a `std::unordered_map` as in this code.  The latter often confers a performance advantage when ordering is not needed, as in this application.

#### Use `std::partial_sort`

We can use [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) with a custom predicate to have the program only order the first `k` entries in the list.  This can be faster than sorting the entire list when only a fraction of the list needs to be sorted.

#### Use `std::copy` where practical

Rather than copy the entries piece by piece, if you can use `std::copy`, it's both more clear to readers of the code and sometimes more efficient.

#### Use existing data structures where practical

The original code uses a custom `Node` class, but it's essentially no different from the `std::pair<int, int>` that is natively used by `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

#### Use `reserve` to avoid dynamically resizing

The revised code uses `reserve` to allocate exactly the number of items needed in the `std::vector`.  This can save time and memory because it avoids reallocation and copying that happens when such data structures must be expanded as items are added.

Comment: Why `std::partial_sort` instead of `std::nth_element`?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good question.  One could use either, but as you probably know, `partial_sort` leaves the top `k` elements in sorted order, while `nth_element` only assures that the set is partitioned.  So the answer would be the same, but of the two, only `partial_sort` leaves the answer in sorted order.  When I need to solve problems like this, I tend to want them sorted, but if that's not needed or wanted, one could probably shave off some CPU cycles by using `nth_element` instead.